# Why doesn't execution stop when 'return' statement is encountered?

Tags: python, return

While I was reading this code:

```
def factorial(number):
    if not isinstance(number, int):
        raise TypeError("Sorry. 'number' must be an integer.")
    if number < 0:
        raise ValueError("Sorry. 'number' must be zero or positive.")
    
    def inner_factorial(number):
        if number <= 1:
            return 1
        return number * inner_factorial(number - 1)
    return inner_factorial(number)
```

I couldn't understand this part of the code:

```
    def inner_factorial(number):
        if number <= 1:
            return 1
        return number * inner_factorial(number - 1)
    return inner_factorial(number)
```

I mean, doesn't Python stop the code, when it sees the statement `return`? I want to know how the `return number * inner_factorial(number - 1)` code line works.

Comment: `return` is used to exit out of a function call. The expression after return is what the function call returns. It doesn't shut down the whole python program in general. That would only happen if there was nothing to run after you exit out of the function.

Comment: Each of those three return statements are in different scopes (which you can see by their different levels of indentation).  The first one only happens within the `if`.  The second one is what happens if the `if` didn't happen.  The third one is completely outside of the `inner_factorial` function and instead returns from the outer `factorial` function.

Comment: The last `return` is for the ***outer*** function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the line `return number * inner_factorial(number - 1)` means that it will return `number` times `inner_factorial(number - 1)`, so the function basically calls itself, and will keep calling itself over and over again until `number <= 1`, where it returns 1. And I think that python doesn't stop the code maybe because the return statement contains `inner_factorial(number - 1)`, which also has to keep running? So maybe the `inner_factorial(number - 1)` call is holding up the program and taking a bit of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you have highlighted belongs to inner function. If it helps, you can think them separately, as follows.

```py
def inner_factorial(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return 1
    return number * inner_factorial(number - 1)  # 1

def factorial(number):
    if not isinstance(number, int):
        raise TypeError("Sorry. 'number' must be an integer.")
    if number < 0:
        raise ValueError("Sorry. 'number' must be zero or positive.")
    
    return inner_factorial(number)  # 2
```

The `factorial` function just returns `inner_factorial` with the same value passed in (Line #2). Then, `inner_factorial` is called and it returns *itself*, which means it is a *recursive call*. `inner_factorial` will be calling itself until the `number` becomes less than or equal to `1`.

---

##### How does the recursion work?

When we run `factorial(4)`, the values are being pushed onto the Call Stack (The Call Stack is the stack data structure that stores information about the active subroutines of a computer program. The Call Stack is important because each task can have it’s own separate stack. This means that each function called can be active simultaneously for different tasks doing different things. Another advantage is that a Call Stack supports recursive calls automatically.) in the program and there will be a new `inner_factorial` function pushed onto the Call Stack until `inner_factorial` returns `1`. To see that, one can use debugger (I use PyCharm's) with break point in the return statement of `inner_factorial` function and use *step into* button.
So, with `factorial(4)`, we populate 4 new `inner_factorials`.

[image]

If I continue clicking in step into button, these `inner_factorials` are being removed one by one. (Being popped off the Call Stack which is why it is happening in reverse order from when it was pushed onto the Call Stack)

Another thing is whether or not this multiplication will be done at once, or sequentially. To test this, instead of using multiplication with `*`, I create a function `multiply` to reveal what is going on under the hood. It appears that multiplication is done as follows:
`2x1 → 3x2 → 4x6`. This behavior can be illustrated by running the script below:

```py
import time


def inner_factorial(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return 1
    time.sleep(1)


    def multiply(a, b):
        print(f"multiplying {a} with {b}.")
        time.sleep(1)
        return a * b
    return multiply(number, inner_factorial(number - 1))  # <- change is in here.
# where multiply (number being popped of the call stack, return a*b)

# multiplying 2 with 1.
# multiplying 3 with 2.
# multiplying 4 with 6.
# 24

inner_factorial(4)
```

If I misinterpret any part and explained wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks,I've made a survey about recursive calls and I figured it out :)

Comment: I get the recursive call but when I step through the code with debugger I don't get where it is storing and calculating everything during run time. I am assuming the function its self is an object and it is storing it there? Is Python just running though inner_factorial then multiplying 4x3x2x1 all at once. Is Python just going 4x3 storing 12 in the function object then 12x2 then sorting 24 then doing 24x1? Running breakpoints at the return it looks like its doing 4x3 -> 3x2 -> 2x1.

Comment: With breakpoints at return statement of innter_factorial, I also observed the similar behavior, 2x1 → 3x2 → 4x3. I updated my answer including how I tested this. Please don't hesitate to ask if something remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def inner_factorial(number):
        if number <= 1:
            return 1
        return number * inner_factorial(number - 1)
    return inner_factorial(number)
```

This part does two things:

1. It defines a function inner_factorial, but does NOT run it.
2. It returns inner_factorial(number), here is where inner_factorial is actually run.

If you define a function B inside function A, Python doesn't just return when it sees the return statement of the inner function B. I think this answers your question.